# CASE WHEN with COLLECT_SET

Tags: hiveql

I have a toy table:

```
hive> SELECT * FROM ds.forgerock;
OK
forgerock.id    forgerock.productname   forgerock.description
1       OpenIDM Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions
2       OpenAM  Full-featured access management
3       OpenDJ  Robust LDAP server for Java
4       OpenDJ  desc2
4       OpenDJ  desc2
Time taken: 0.083 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

I am trying to get a table like:

```
id          flag
1           0
2           0
3           1
4           1
```

I am using the toy table to iterate and develop working code.

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN "OpenDJ" IN COLLECT_SET(productname) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag, 
GROUP BY id FROM ds.forgerock;
```

Note that in the toy data set, every `id` only has one distinct value, so `COLLECT_SET` doesn't seem necessary. However, given the actual data set actually has more than one distinct value, what I am trying to do will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max()` for flag aggregation by id:

```
SELECT id, max(CASE WHEN productname='OpenDJ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag 
  FROM ds.forgerock
 GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: only my toy data set has one `id`. my actual data has multiple distinct values per id.